# Page not scrolling to top when route changes in Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js

I'm trying to always go on the top of the page when route changes with Nuxt.

So I've put this into my `app/router.scrollBehavior.js` file:

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

But it always returns to the last saved position (which is always `null` in my console by the way).

Any idea of what I could miss here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How not to scroll up page after changing route in Nuxt js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814605/how-not-to-scroll-up-page-after-changing-route-in-nuxt-js)

Comment: Thanks @kissu, but no. I'd like the exact opposite behavior : always scroll up, or even better (with a transition maybe), always arriving at the top of the page without scrolling.

Comment: Hi, did you opened the linked question? It was poorly named, but still please give it a read. Because at the end, it is explaining how the whole scrolling behavior works in Nuxt, hence you should be able to have it working regardless of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @kissu, no I didn't, but I'm gonna do that now and give you my feedback after that. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @kissu sorry, but this didn't help me. I tried all the solutions but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please add more details on what you've tried, what is not working and maybe give us a [repro] to help you faster!

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about making a codesandbox and maybe I'll understand something important during the process :)

Comment: @kissu 
well... in my minimal demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-bush-l2v6z, 
all works as expected (besides it seems that this is the default behavior of Nuxt to always return on top when route changes).
So maybe I've something that blocks this natural behavior. Maybe a GSAP timeline that isn't destroyed on route changes. I'm gonna inspect this a little bit further.

Comment: You probably have a typo somewhere? Or something pretty simple that may conflict with the scroll behavior?

Comment: @kissu It seems that its related to some GSAP scroll animations. When I disable them, almost everything is working fine :)

Comment: Yeah, be careful when mixing those libraries. Btw, I do have this question, not sure if it may interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424070/8816585

Comment: Also, if your issue is solved. Mind if I post an answer stating that it was basically a GSAP conflict?

Comment: Yes @kissu, no problem for me that you post an answer. I made a copy of my project and disabled Gsap everywhere to be sure and all is working fine. I've spotted some places where I don't destroy the timelines and/or scrollTriggers, so I guess this is where my problem is located. For your question on LocomotiveScroll, there is a great tutorial on how to implement it with GSAP step by step here : 
https://www.creativecodingclub.com/courses/scrolltrigger-express (10$ a month)

Comment: Haha, the linked question is not one of mine, I've actually answered to this one.

Comment: @kissu, yes I saw this :)

Answer (score 14):

For Nuxt v3.0.0-rc.3

Create file named `route.global.ts` on `middleware/` folder

Then write this in file:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.path !== from.path && process.client) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
})
```

Comment: Still working on RC12 for the record.

Answer (score 11):

I use Nuxt 3 (npm:nuxt3@3.0.0-rc.4-27588443.cf25525), none of the solutions work for me.
Finally this works:

`/plugins/scrollToTop.js` (any filename will work, just put it in the plugins folder)

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.$router.options.scrollBehavior = async (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (to.path !== from.path && process.client) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Nuxt 3**

My solution was to create a file in the `middleware` folder with the following stucture:

```ts
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  useNuxtApp().hook("page:finish", () => {
    if (history.state.scroll) {
      setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(history.state.scroll), 0);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), 0);
    }
  });
})
```

and I named it `fix-scroll-position.global.ts`.

The `setTimeout` is used to avoid the weird jumping to the top, meaning that the user won't see the page scrolling to the top.

This snippet ensures that the page scrolls to the top when the routes change, and that the scroll position is kept when the back button is clicked. The last functionality is achieved using `history.state.scroll`, that checks if there is a scroll position saved from the previous route.

Comment: PS: this answer is for Nuxt3.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#scrollbehavior

```
The router.scrollBehavior.js file must be in the app folder, which in turn is in the project's root.
```

the file should name **router.scrollBehavior.js**.

You can console.log something in this function and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Cianekjr, I forgot the "router." part in my question. It's how I named it in fact, so my question remains.

Answer (score 2):

At the end, [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) was conflicting with OP's scrolling behavior.
Removing it, solved all the issues related to Nuxt, nothing was actually wrong with the `router.scrollBehavior.js` file.

Comment: How do you find out if this is the case @kissu?

Comment: @BorisKamp in OP's case that was the issue. If you want to see if it's the same in your case, you can probably try to remove it from your project! I mean, that or anything that may conflict with the default behavior of some scroll interaction.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer is not the correct way of doing it.

Create a file in `app` directory called `router.options.js`

```js
// app/router.options.js
export default {
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 }
  }
}
```

#### With typescript (recommended)

```js
// app/router.options.ts
import type { RouterOptions } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterOptions> {
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's not correct, it serves a different purpose while still being flexible (if you don't want that behavior everywhere). It's less generic/global but it is achieving the same result.

Comment: The scroll behavior might (actually should) change, since it’s a bit glitchy rn. The correct way to configure scroll behavior is through the scrollBehavior config. 

When the scrolling bug is fixed, the scroll will look much better than with the middleware “trick”.

Comment: What I mean is that both solutions are viable, depends if you want it fully global or in a middleware. Thanks for your input tho!

Comment: this solution, first scrolls to top and then changes the route. what I think the OP is asking is to change the route to the top, not route to top and then change.

Comment: This is currently not possible in nuxt unfortunately… sucks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, so therefore an answer. A simple note, but I think it may help some.

I struggled with this as well and nothing worked, but after a while I found out the culprit. My layout looked like this

```html
<template>

  <div id="page" class="flex flex-col h-screen overflow-scroll bg-white">
    <Navbar />

    <slot />

    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

That div around the components has the height of the screen and the page content scrolls in that div, but therefore the window is always at the top and you won't see any scrolling when clicking on NuxtLink.

I use nuxt 3.0.0 and when I let the `#page` div grow with the content (ie. removing the `h-screen` and `overflow-scroll` tailwind classes), it has the scroll to top behavior even without the solutions from above.

So, if you have this problem with the stable nuxt 3 version, check your html.

Comment: This is totally fine as an answer tbh.

Answer (score 0):

The current default behavior fixed this issue and behaves just like a native link change. Please remove any custom scrollBehavior configuration and update to the newest version of Nuxt.

Comment: You should probably edit your other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893669/8816585

Answer (score 0):

The default scroll behaviour of Nuxt is scrolling to Top with a smooth behaviour. I my case this wasn't something I want.

I needed a router which scroll to top without smooth behaviour, which goes to hashes with a smooth behaviour and respects the scrollMargin Property and scroll to savedPosition.

This is my suggestion for Nuxt3 (3.6.1)

/app/router.options.js

```
const scrollToElement = (hashElement) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(hashElement);
  if (element) {
    let scrollMargin = 0 // default there is no scrollMargin
    // read elements scrollMargin if it has one in css
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element); // Get all styles of an element
    if (style.scrollMarginTop) scrollMargin = parseInt(style.scrollMarginTop);
    window.scrollTo({ top: element.offsetTop - scrollMargin, behavior: "smooth" }); 
  }
};

export default {
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) window.scrollTo(savedPosition);
    else if (to.hash && from.path === to.path) {
      scrollToElement(to.hash);
    } else if (to.hash && from.path !== to.path) { // if hash is on a different page
      useNuxtApp().hook("page:transition:finish", () => {
        scrollToElement(to.hash);
      });
    }
    
    else if (to.path !== from.path){

      // Wait until the page is rendered
      // Otherwise it scrolls to top when the transition starts 
      // before the actually page is changed
      useNuxtApp().hook("page:transition:finish", () => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Nuxt 3 to achieve:

1. Scroll always to a saved position, if it's set
2. Scroll to the hash if it is present
3. Scroll to the top if the two previous conditions are not met

This code goes in `app/router.options.ts`

```js
import type {
  RouterConfig
} from "nuxt/schema";

export default < RouterConfig > {
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition ?
      savedPosition :
      to.hash ?
      {
        el: to.hash
      } :
      {
        top: 0
      };
  },
};
```

Nuxt uses the vue router under the hood, so you can see the details here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html