Scroll to top doesn't work on NuxtJs, VueJs, Typescript and Prismic project
I have a problem on my nuxt (v3.11.2) project with vuejs (v3.4.21) and typescript, when I press a link, I arrive at the bottom of the window instead of arriving at the top, I had already tried to put a scroll to top in OnMounted, but nothing helps, I have the problem on almost all pages. This often happens when I'm on the footer and I click on a link. Byt the way, when I go to a link and go down and then go back, it keeps the same height. if you have any answer, don't hesitate, thank you.

I think this might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902990/page-not-scrolling-to-top-when-route-changes-in-nuxt-js

I already tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902990/page-not-scrolling-to-top-when-route-changes-in-nuxt-js
It's doesn't work anyway

Lots of irrelevant details and no [repro] so far. I am not sure how you think we can help you anyhow here.
