# Locomotive scroll doesn't work in my Nuxt3 project

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, locomotive-scroll

I'm using locomotive scroll and nuxt3. This is my repo:  https://github.com/cyprianwaclaw/nuxt.git

I imported `async locomotive-scroll` in layouts/scroll and added this layout in main app, but the scrolling is not smooth.

My styleccs are in the assets/css/tailwindcss file.

How can I make the scrolling smooth in my project?

And in my console I have this error:

```
locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7 
    
   Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetHeight')
at n.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:11013)
at n.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:10771)
at s.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:29026)
at new s (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:28450)
at scroll.70d56592.mjs:1:397
```

Comment: Hi, can you give a try to that one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66423288/8816585 Maybe there are some conflicts with Tailwind? Did you tried without? Also, do you have an error anywhere or found an issue related on the project?

Comment: yes, in my console I have this error:

Comment: Feel free to update your question directly.

Comment: locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetHeight')
    at n.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:11013)
    at n.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:10771)
    at s.value (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:29026)
    at new s (locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7:28450)
    at scroll.70d56592.mjs:1:397
locomotive-scroll.esm.526a65ed.mjs:7

Comment: vercel link: https://nuxt-dun.vercel.app/

Comment: Providing the result will not help anyhow here. Especially since we do have an actual error here. Where are you calling `offsetHeight` exactly?

Comment: offsetHeight is locomotive-scroll file, you would like this error in vercel (link is upper) in console (I don't good speak English)

Answer (score 0):

try add css style in nuxt.confi.ts :

```js
css: [
  '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
  'locomotive-scroll/dist/locomotive-scroll.css',
],
```